# Assigning Value to StringValue In F#

Tags: f#

I am working though [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-create-a-spreadsheet-document-by-providing-a-file-name) example of the Open XML SDK using F#

When I get to this line of code

```
sheet.Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart)
```

I am getting a null ref exception when I implement it like this:

```
sheet.Id.Value <- document.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart)
```

Is there another way to assign that value?  System.Reflection?

Comment: Can You show more code? The link provided doesn't contain F# code samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working like this:

```
let sheet = new Sheet
                (
                    Id = new StringValue(spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart)), 
                    SheetId = UInt32Value.FromUInt32(1u), 
                    Name = new StringValue("mySheet")
                )
```

If You want to take a look to the entire sample translated to F#, it's [here](https://gist.github.com/blainne/3eb2b24eafe518cb4ba01103937c0517).

Answer (score 2):

To clarify what's going on, the problem is that `sheet.Id` is initially `null`. If we look at the following:

```
sheet.Id.Value <- document.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart)
```

The code tries to access the `sheet.Id` and invoke its `Value` property setter, but the `Id` itself is `null`. The answer posted by Grzegorz sets the value of the whole `Id` property - it's done in a construtor syntax, but it's equivalent to writing the following:

```
sheet.Id <- new StringValue(spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart))
```

This sets the whole `Id` property to a new `StringValue` instance.